# Css auto centering problem

Tags: html, css, center

I have a search form with a text field and a button on the same line. A div wrapping the form has `margin:auto;` and `width:20%;`. However, the problem is that when I resize the browser and make the width shorter, eventually 20% becomes too narrow for the entire form to fit, and the button moves over to the next line. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

add a style for `min-width`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Comment: +1 for beating me to the same answer. See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/GvQbq/